# How many cycles in this adjacency matrix?

Tags: combinatorics, permutation-cycles, adjacency-matrix

Consider the $N\times N$ adjacency matrix $A$ such that
$$A_{ij}=\begin{cases} 1, &\; \; (i\leq n \;\text{ or }\; j \leq n), \;\; i\neq j \\ 0, & \; \; \text{otherwise}\end{cases} $$
for some integer $0\leq n \leq N$

Example matrix, $N=5, n=3$

$$\begin{pmatrix}0&1&1&1&1 \\ 1&0&1&1&1 \\ 1&1&0&1&1 \\ 1&1&1&0&0 \\ 1&1&1&0&0 \end{pmatrix}$$

Example matrix, $N=7, n=4$

$$\begin{pmatrix}0&1&1&1&1&1&1 \\ 1&0&1&1&1&1&1 \\ 1&1&0&1&1&1&1 \\ 1&1&1&0&1&1&1 \\ 1&1&1&1&0&0&0 \\ 1&1&1&1&0&0&0 \\ 1&1&1&1&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

[image]

Question: How many cycles are in $A(N,n)$?

I only need the answers for $A(30,5)$ and $A(30,7)$ but I am curious about the general case.

Comment: What have you tried? There is a very natural setup. Have you interpreted the graph?

Comment: @CalvinLin This isn't an exercise it has come about from a project that I am working on. I wasn't sure how to approach it so posted here to hopefully get the answer.

Comment: Doesn't matter whether or not it is an "exercise from a book" or something that you came up with. What have you tried?

Comment: Are you distinguishing cycles from their reversals? From cyclic permutations of themselves?

Comment: I haven't as I couldn't see any way to approach the problem.

@BrianM.Scott I distinguish reversals, but not cyclic permutations.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Interpret the graph as 1) Complete graph on $n$ elements, 2) $N-n$ elements that are connected only to the vertices of the complete graph.

**Hint:** View a $k-$cycle as a $k-$permutation of $N$. What are the restrictions?

> For a $k-$ cycle to be valid, the only restriction is that elements that are $ > n$ cannot be located next to each other. Hence, we can
>  1. Pick $\frac{k}{2} \leq l \leq k$ elements from $1$ to $n$,
>  2. Pick $k - l $ elements from $n+1$ to $N$,
>  3. Pick $k-l$ spots from $l$ spots to insert the large elements
>  4. Divide out by $k$ if desired to count unique cycles.
>  5. Sum over all $l$ possible values.

Sum up over all $k$. Note that $k \leq 2n$.

Comment: I'm sure these are good hints. Sadly I do not know what to do with them.

Are you saying that the overall number of cycles is just the cycles in $K_N - K_n$?

Comment: I have added in a diagram to show my interpretation.

Comment: @BenCrossley I've added the details. There will be a bunch of tedious calculation (which is to be expected, given that it's somewhat unlikely for an "arbitrary" count to always work out nicely)

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll make this a mini project to try and write some code that does this.

Answer (score 1):

Calvin gave a better answer, but here is another one that is a bit more computational:

If $A$ is an adjacency matrix, then $a_{ij}=1$ means there is a direct path from $i$ to $j$.  Consider $A^2$. Its elements are $a_{ij} a_{jk}$ --- so a 1 means there a path from $i$ to $j$, $j$ to $k$, so from $i$ to $k$.  What is the diagonal?  $a_{ij} a_{ji}$ --- a path from $i$ to $j$ and back to $i$.

If you keep computing matrix powers, $A^k$, you'll trace out all the paths in the graph, and the diagonal will accumulate the cycles from each vertex back to itself. Since you only need two cases, you could compute the $A^k$ matrix directly in MATLAB or something and get all the information about paths and cycles.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot code. I've recently started learning python but I can't see how to write this yet.

Comment: $\mathrm{tr}(A^k)$ counts the number of closed walks of length $k$, not cycles. The difference is closed walks can repeat vertices, while cycles cannot. I am pretty sure the matrix power trick cannot be salvages to count cycles.